# How should I design my tcp server program to make `IHostedService`s communicate with each other

Tags: c#, .net-core, tcpserver

I'm re-writing a tcp server program in .net core.
I have difficulties  implementing my design.

The server has three basic functions/services:

- service 1. accept and manage client connections
- service 2. handle each kind of client messages and send acknowledge message
- service 3. keep track of inactive clients(clients who haven't sent any message for a time) and close those connections.

I'd like to have each of these functions on a dedicate `IHostedService`.
But I've no idea how should these services communicate with each other.

These services are registered by `AddHostedService`, and seem can't be injected.

And I'm not sure if it's a correct way to expose public methods on a Hosted Service for others to call.

The most relevant SO question I've found is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52524636/ihostedservice-for-tcp-servers-in-net-core).

In my situation, it means that I should register one mediator service for each of the three services. It doesn't seem to be a clean way because these mediators are just for communication, without semantic meanings...

I'd like to know if the mediator is the only approach,
or is my design totally incorrect?

Comment: What do you mean "can't be injected"? Do you mean you want to inject your hosted service into another service?

Comment: @John yes, I mean .net core's dependency injection

Comment: @John thank you...but i still don't get how to inject them. Because all services are injected as `IHostedService` interface, one cann't distinguish between them via DI...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That really depends on strategy.  Each hosted service could take in a configuration as part of its dependencies for communication.  However, TCP port binding will need to be unique.

In a prior life, I wrote a UDP service that broadcast and which TCP services were available for communication and mediated the services in chat room sort of setup. UDP is more of a wide net whereas TCP is specific addressing.

If you were using only TCP, without configuration those services would need to know who is the mediator and what address to reach it at.

Comment: The three functions I described run in the same .net core consle app, they make up my tcp server program.... My really doubt is how should they communicate with each other in my app, because DI seems not work for IHostedService...

Comment: I see, I misread thinking they were different apps. DI isn't the place for communication, the right thing here is to expose public properties for each based on responsibilities. I would implement each as derived implementations such as `ITcpManagermentService : IHostedService` and `ITcpFilterService : IHostedService` and `ITcpMonitorService : IHostedService`. This supports SOLID implementation purity by separating responsibility, providing appropriate substitution, interface segregation and thus support for clean DI. AutoFac does work for IHostedService btw, use it all the time

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, should the derived implementations still be registered via `AddHostedService`? I'm not sure whether the service provider may resolve the derived implementations registered by `AddHostedService`,  but I'll have a try. Thank you.

Comment: I tested, instances registered via `AddHostedService` can't be resolved by interface type. I think I have no choice but to use a mediator....

Comment: Sorry this is late. I use Autofac as an IoC to register my services.  An example of this is https://github.com/DanielMPries/XService/blob/Release/XService.Driver/Program.cs#L99

Comment: I think AutoFac could not solve the issue how `Hostedservices` could call into each other. Nevertheless, I've already done my work by mediator classes.... And thank you for your answer, your XService project  is enlightening for me.